# Set x-scroll to infinity and disable y-scroll

Tags: html, css

[image: the green part is the visible part of the page, the white part is out of view]

I want a way of disabling vertical scrolling, while making all contents of a div lie next to each other so that they go out of the visible browser window, but x-scrolling can bring them into the browser window. How do I do this using css?

Comment: Your drawing suggests you want vertical scrolling (aka y-scrolling) while your text states the exact opposite. Can you please clarify?

Comment: You can either attempt to code it yourself and ask us if you get stuck or hire a developer. SO is about improving your coding skills, or debugging existing code, not about other people doing your work for you, free of charge.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu Well, I'm not asking for someone to do it free of charge, I'm trying to get a solution to a problem. I've tried coding it myself and failed several times. Which is why I want a fresh suggestion.

Comment: @morido, I want x-scrolling on the bottom div.

Comment: Ok, finally I believe I figured out what you want: The entire green part of your drawing behaves ordinarily. But the *bottom part* exceeds the viewport to the right and you want it to be only x-scrollable - thus creating some sort of "timeline" in the footer of your page.

Comment: @TroubleZero in that case you need to show us your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (hoping that I inferred your intention correctly):

```css
body {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.bottom {
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

.sample_content {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1000px; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    main part
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="sample_content">
        some wide content
      </div>
      <div class="sample_content">
        some more wide content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class='main-part'>
  <div class='main-part-inner'>
    <!-- your content goes here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main-part {
  width: 500px; /* width of your scrolling div */
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.main-part-inner {
  width: 2000px; /* width of your scrolled content */
}
```